# How can I add unique keys to <TouchableOpacity> components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

I am trying to generate unique keys for some `<TouchableOpacity>` components that I would like to pass in `onPress` but it's not picking up the `key` variable.

```js
const options = ["pic1","pic2","pic2"];

export default function ColourScreen() {
    
    const handlePress = (key) => {
       ...do something wity key...
    }

    return (
        
        <View>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={key => handlePress(key)}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.icon}
                    source={require('../../../assets/icons/icon_1.jpg')}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={key => handlePress(key)}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.icon}
                    source={require('../../../assets/icons/icon_2.jpg')}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={key => handlePress(key)}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.icon}
                    source={require('../../../assets/icons/icon_3.jpg')}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

    )
}
```

I've tried manually setting it like:

```js
<TouchableOpacity 
    key = {1}
    onPress={key => handlePress(key)}>
    <Image
        style={styles.icon}
        source={require('../../../assets/icons/icon_1.jpg')}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

or:

```js
{options.map((option, key) =>
    <TouchableOpacity
        key = {key}
        onPress={() => handlePress(key)}>
    <Image
        style={styles.icon}
        source={require('../../../assets/icons/icon_1.jpg')}
     />
    </TouchableOpacity>, ...

)}
```

But this just creates multiple components.

How can I successfully do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the key and map it to your icon.

```
const icons = [
  require(`../../../assets/icons/icon_1.jpg`),
  reqiuire(`../../../assets/icons/icon_2.jpg`),
  require(`../../../assets/icons/icon_3.jpg`),
  require(`../../../assets/icons/icon_4.jpg`),
]

{options.map((option, key) =>
    <TouchableOpacity
        key = {key}
        onPress={() => handlePress(key)}>
    <Image
        style={styles.icon}
        source={icons[key]}
     />
    </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Comment: For some reason there is an error with the string interpolation. `Invalid call at line 103: require("../../../assets/icons/icon_" + (Number(key) + 1) + ".jpg")`

Comment: ```"../../../assets/icons/icon_" + (Number(key) + 1) + ".jpg"``` -> Should be like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when my data do not have unique id I use this approach with lodash

```
 import { map, uniqueId } from 'lodash'

 {map(someArray, () => (
        <React.Fragment key={uniqueId()}>
          <TextButton />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply, do this.

```
<TouchableOpacity
 onPress={() => yourFunctionName(1)}
> 
  your text or image goes here
<TouchableOpacity />

const yourFunctionName = (id) => {
 console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).